# MySQL - Check if a data in table exist in the other table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am developing a mini restaurant management system and I have these database design.

This is my "**TABLE**" table.

[image: TABLES table]

This is my **"ORDERS"** table.

[image: ORDERS table]

I would like to make a query that will determine whether a table is **vacant** or **occupied**. I have a column in my orders table called `has_paid`, I would like to make that column as my basis whether the table is vacant or occupied. The orders table is connected to my "tables" table because of the `table_id` in the orders table.

Ideally, I would like to have a query that would result in something like this:

```
table.id | table.name | available or occupied
   1     |   table 1  |  available
   2     |   table 2  |  occupied
   3     |   table 3  |  occupied
   4     |   table 4  |  available
```

Take note also that the `orders` table will have a data that will contain repeating table id. Like the scenario is that multiple customers have used the same table within the day.

I don't have any idea on how to make a query like this. Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks Stackoverflow!

Comment: Please explain how you define available or occupied if when there are multiple matches.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - i think if the `has_paid` = 0, that means the table is occupied, else, it is vacant.

Comment: Please share the tables as text data tables (like you did with the results) or share the SQL statements (CREATE and INSERT statements) on www.sqlfiddle.com instead off images... this way you get much better help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all likelihood, you want the most recent record from `orders`.  One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select (case when has_paid = 0 then 'occupied' else 'vacant' end)
        from orders o
        where o.table_id = t.table_id
        order by o.id desc
        limit 1
       ) as vacant_or_occupied
from tables t;
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer! I tried your query and it seems to be working nicely! but I noticed that when a table does not exist in the orders table it returns NULL, but i guess if it is NULL, that means the table is vacant.

Comment: @PinoyStackOverflower . . . I don't know what your business rules are for tables with no rows in `orders`.